# Raspberry CM3 + additional sd card

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd-card

I want to use Raspberry Compute Module 3 (CM3) for an industrial project.
The problem is that 4GB of emmc (connected to SD0 broadcom private bus) is not enough.
I want to connect an additional SD card (8GB) throught the second SD interface SD1 (GPIO from 22 to 27 in ALT3).
The problem is that with this connection and with the default Raspbian Lite jessy (kernel 4.4) the connected sdcard is not recognized.
I tried to set the gpio alternate (ALT3) function with cli raspi-gpio but no results.
What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, as I havent worked with the CM3, but there is a CM3L option, that forgoes the 4GB of eMMC flash and allows you to provide the SD card. https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/compute-module-3-lite/

Comment: I have found the problem: you have to set into /boot/config.txt the dtoverlay=sdio in order to enable this function.

Answer (score 1):

We are using the CM3L version (no on-board flash), and my references are to the schematic titled "Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3 (reduced)", dated 10-13-2016.
The CM3L cannot access an external SD card because the control lines are not brought out to the card-edge pins.  We modified our CM3 samples, turning them into CM3L units with the following steps to remove the on-board flash and to bring the control lines to the card-edge pins (notes taken from my marked-up schematic):

To turn CM3 into CM3L:

- Move R24 to R25 position
- Short R12, R16, R17, R18, R19
- Remove U7 (BGA Flash)
- Not documented, but seems to be necessary: R9 should be zero Ohms,
  and R8 is listed as a 2.2k Pull-up, but seems to be zero Ohms. Move R8 to
  R9 position (or maybe just short across R9 pads.

Answer (score 0):

Posssible using other gpio but not sd0, eg. Dev board won't do without modification.

See this thread. The other answer isn't ideal IMHO as you can't use both and are permanently modifying your compute.

> You can have the 2nd SDIO peripheral at GPIO 22-27 or 34-39.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=172406